# How is the data between Database Server and User Application is transfered in ADO.Net

Tags: c#, .net, database, ado.net

Means the format of data, is it transfered in XML Format or TextFile or is there any other way of trasfering data in ADO.Net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ADO.NET is set of interfaces, abstract classes and classes which let database providers implement a database access in a common way for all products in the market on top of .NET Framework.

Each ADO.NET provider could be implemented in different ways, there's no restriction about how native communication between database and data layer happens.

You can easly check how some providers do that (SQL Server, MySQL...) using a network sniffer and see packets' contents or downloading providers' source code - if it's an open sourced project! -.